# hide all td's with same id with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

```
<td id="valhisprofitVal"><%= Math.Round(profit, 5) %>%</td>
```

These rows are added dynamically, so there can be multiple rows with the same Id.

How do I hide all of them using Jquery?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't. Only one element can have its own ID, you can't share the same ID among multiple elements. And because of that, if you try to use JavaScript to find elements with the same ID, you'll only obtain the first of those elements.

Use a class instead:

```
<td class="valhisprofitVal"><%= Math.Round(profit, 5) %>%</td>
```

Then in jQuery, select the class:

```
$('.valhisprofitVal').hide();
```

Comment: There is just one thing that bothers me a bit. This css class is unknown.  Since you are using a css to define a behavior, it actually couples the presentation of the element to its functionality.